# compiler/linker error while building app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

My app crashes if I try to build it.
It says: `linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Here's the crash:

[image]

Comment: That is not a crash but a compiler/linker error - quite some time before your app is able to launch at all.

Comment: Ok, I'll change the topic. Do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately not really, has to do something with your imports probably - but nothing I can really help with :/

Comment: You could try cleaning the build. That seems to fix it in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

1. Goto application's target
2. Compile Sources
3. Remove duplicate file using (-).

Also this problem may occur just because of typo when including the header; so check that the header file (.h) is included and not the implementation file (.m)

And [here](http://angelolloqui.com/blog/31-How-to-fix-a-Duplicated-Symbols-error-on-binary-files) is a cool article about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

⌘ + B.

If that doesn't work

1- Click on `Product`

2- Hold down `option` to reveal hidden menu.

3- Click `Clean Build Folder`